# Process interaction(c# and pure c++)

Tags: c#, .net, c++, process, interaction

I've got c# dispatcher and fast c++ program for data processing.I need pass data(initializtion) to c++ program from c# dispatcher.
Passing data is primitive type: config strings, decimals.
I don't want use file or command line arguments for interaction. I think it should be smarter way. Now interaction is one-way, but I think at the future it could be two way.
Can you advice me appropriate way for my task?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you could make use of C++/CLI DLL as the middle layer.

Comment: @Daniel: C++/CLI interop doesn't require marshaling in most cases, and has much better performance than any inter-process communications (since IPC does require marshaling).

Answer (score 0):

You could use environment variables, that's a common method for passing options and data to a child process.

If you have the C++ source code, I like @ghimireniraj's idea of making the C++ code into a .NET assembly using the C++/CLI compiler, then you don't actually need to start a separate program, and you can pass your data as function arguments.